Ultisnips transformation not working as desired
I have written the following snippet for UltiSnips in Vim. With this snippet I want to add an apostrophe to all lilypond pitches:
snippet 1 "lilypond pitches with apostophes"
$1
${1/\w+\s*/$0'/g}
endsnippet

When I execute it, however, the text appears twice:
c d e
c' d' e'

I just want the 2nd line
I've tried snippet 1 "lilypond pitches with apostophes"
snippet 1
${1/\w+\s*/$0'/g}
endsnippet

but this gives an error:
UltiSnips Error:

Tabstop 1 is not known but is used by a Transformation

